# Appending to elements in a Bash associative array

Tags: arrays, csv

My name is Mike and I am a total noob at Bash programming.  With that being said, please don't chew me to a pulp.  Here's my scenario.  I'm importing a csv and processing it line by line.  It looks up information in AD and pipes that result to a variable $ADresult1.

I then take that output and send it into the array.

```
declare -A arrmail
arrmail[$ADresult1]="$v1, $v3"
appendvar+="; ${arrmail[$ADresult1]}"
if [ ! -z "${arrmail[$ADresult1]}" ]; then
    echo ${arrmail[@]}
else
    echo ${arrmail[@]}="$appendvar"
fi
```

Now in my CSV file, the var `$ADresult1` has more than one entry that is the same, however each element should be different.

For example:  The first line might contain `arrmail[p100]=Y2K, Y2J`
The second line might `arrmail[p100]=GGG, GG1`

My question would be how to combine the elements from the first line and second line into one line of output and/or if this is possible.

For instance `arrmail[p100]=Y2K, Y2J; GGG, GG1`

If needs be, I can post the whole entire script for a bigger picture.

Here's the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

###--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Author : Volha Zhdanava (p146819)
# Date   : 11-FEB-2013
# Purpose: To automate the process of sending out notification emails to developers when 
# Assigned DEV Machine is on the Expired Devices List.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#            ----MODIFIED----
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Author               Revsn Date      Revsn ID        Revsn Purpose
# Mike Bell         02-28-14    Rev.03      Add ability to email j or p number
# Mike Bell     01-02-15    Rev.04      Add verbiage about 90 day licensing
###----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Purple='\e[1;35m'
ColorOFF='\e[0m'
TO_TEAM="dev-tools@edwardjones.com"

#-----------------------------------------
#Ask for input CSV file
#-----------------------------------------

FILEDIR="/export/share/is/dev_env/expdev"
FILENAME="expired_devices.csv"

#if the directory is not empty, find the csv file
if [[ $(ls -A $FILEDIR) ]]
then
#check if the csv file was stored with default name <expired_devices.csv>

       if [ -f $FILEDIR/$FILENAME ]
      then
#absolute path to the downloaded file
       CSVFILE=`echo $FILEDIR/$FILENAME`
#if the csv file was stored under a user-defined name,
#re-define the absolute path to that file

      else  
             #count how many files are saved in the expdev directory
             NAME=( `ls -A $FILEDIR` )
             CNT=${#NAME[@]}
             echo -e "There is/are ${Purple}${CNT}${ColorOFF} file(s) in the ${Purple}$FILEDIR${ColorOFF} directory:"
         echo ${NAME[@]}
        #if there is only one file saved within the expdev directory
                if [ ${CNT} -eq 1 ]
                   then
                     FILENAME=${NAME[0]}          
                   else
        #it will prompt to enter the name of the file
                 REPLY="n"
                 while [ "$REPLY" != "y" ]  
                 do
                  echo -e "Please enter the full name of the downloaded csv file: \c"
                  read FILENAME
                  echo -e "You entered ${Purple}$FILENAME${ColorOFF}. Is this correct? y/n: \c\n"
                  read ANSWER 
                  REPLY=`echo $ANSWER | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
                 done
                 fi
              #verify the specified file exists in <expdev> directory 

              echo `ls -Al $FILEDIR/$FILENAME` 
              echo -e "\nThe script will run against the listed above ${Purple}$FILENAME${ColorOFF} file.\n${Purple}NOTE${ColorOFF}: Do NOT proceed if it says ${Purple}No such file or directory${ColorOFF}.\nWould you like to proceed? y/n -->:\c "
                 read PROCEED
                 PROCEED=`echo $PROCEED | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
                     if [ "$PROCEED" == "y" ]
                           #user agrees
                       then
                        CSVFILE=`echo $FILEDIR/$FILENAME`
                       else
                        echo -e "Make sure you saved your CSV file in ${Purple}$FILEDIR${ColorOFF} directory and run the script again."
                        exit 1
                     fi

        fi
#----------------------------------------------
#Remove header from CSVFILE
#and create a temp csvfile.txt 
#for "WHILE READ" loop
#----------------------------------------------
Nrows=`cat ${CSVFILE}| wc -l`
N=`expr $Nrows - 1`
tail -$N ${CSVFILE} > csvfile.txt
#----------------------------------------------
#Determine the Extension Date
#----------------------------------------------
TODAYsDATE=`date +"%a"`
case $TODAYsDATE in
Mon ) ExtDate=`date --date='4 day' +"%A, %d-%b-%Y"`
    ;;
Tue ) ExtDate=`date --date='6 day' +"%A, %d-%b-%Y"`
    ;;
Wed ) ExtDate=`date --date='6 day' +"%A, %d-%b-%Y"`
    ;;
Thu ) ExtDate=`date --date='6 day' +"%A, %d-%b-%Y"`
    ;;
Fri ) ExtDate=`date --date='6 day' +"%A, %d-%b-%Y"`
    ;;
* ) echo "Cannot determine the Extention Date."
    REPLY="n"
    while [ "$REPLY" != "y" ]
    do
    echo -e "Please enter Extended Date: \c"
    read ExtDate
    echo -e "You entered ${Purple}$ExtDate${ColorOFF}. Is this correct? y/n: \c "
    read ANSWER
    REPLY=`echo $ANSWER | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
    done

esac

echo -e "The Extended Date for the Application Owners will be ${Purple}$ExtDate${ColorOFF}.\nPlease make a note for End Date in the APEX Workstation Tracking Tool." 

#create a temp confirmation file that will be sent to dev-tools
echo -e "\nThe Extended Date is $ExtDate.\nSent emails to: " > confirmation.txt

#----------------------------------------------
#Read the csvfile.txt
#----------------------------------------------
while IFS=','  read v1 v2 v3 v4 other
do

#----------------------------------------------
#Determine email address
#----------------------------------------------
v2=` echo $v2 | tr '"/,\&' ' ' `
NAME=( ${v2} )
cnt=${#NAME[@]}
#-----------------------------------------------
# Filter j or p<number> userids from table V2
#--------------------------------------------------

if [[ "$NAME" =~ [P|p][[:digit:]]{6}$|[J|j][[:digit:]]{5}$ ]]

    then
        ADresult1=`getent passwd "$NAME" | awk -F":" '{print $1}'`
echo ${ADresult1}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Processing Array
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare -A arrmail

arrmail[$ADresult1]="$v1, $v3"

appendvar+="; ${arrmail[$ADresult1]}"

if [ ! -z "${arrmail[$ADresult1]}" ]

        then
               echo ${arrmail[@]}
else

        echo ${arrmail[@]}="$appendvar"
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If query matches j or p#, then email user
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#
#           v1=` echo $v1 | tr '"' ' ' `
#                        SUBJECT=" ${v1}, ${v3} - Your Development Machine Status Update"
#
#                        TO="${ADresult1}@edwardjones.com"
#
#                        v4=` echo $v4 | tr '"' ' ' `
#
#           devmailmessage="\nGreetings ${NAME[0]}, \n\nI am in the process of cleaning up the machines in our lab.\n\nAssigned device: ${v1} \n\nEffort: ${v3}\n\nThe above machine have been assigned to you since ${v4}.\n\nDo you still need this machine or can I reclaim it?\nIf this machine is still required, please let us know how much longer you will need it.\nPlease keep in mind that Dev. workstations or laptops can only be assigned for 90 days due to licensing restrictions.\n\nIf this machine is no longer needed, please let us know also.\n\nThis machine will be rebuilt on or after $ExtDate.\n\nPlease reply to dev-tools@edwardjones.com by $ExtDate.\n\n\nThank you,\n\nDevelopment Environment Support team\ndev-tools@edwardjones.com " 
#
#echo -e ${devmailmessage}|mail -s "$SUBJECT" $TO -- -f $TO_TEAM

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If query does not match j or p number, then lookup username via first and last name
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

elif [ ${cnt} -eq 2 ]

    then

        ADresult=`getent passwd | grep -i "${NAME[0]}" | grep -i "${NAME[1]}"`

echo ${ADresult}
#count search results from Active Directory; only email if there is one unique result
        ADsearch1=`echo ${ADresult} | grep -i "${NAME[0]}" | wc -l`
        ADsearch2=`echo ${ADresult} | grep -i "${NAME[1]}" | wc -l`
                if [ ${ADsearch1} -eq 1 ] && [ ${ADsearch2} -eq 1 ]
                   then
                        pNumber=`echo ${ADresult} | awk -F":" '{print $1}'`
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Processing Array
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#declare -A arrmail

#arrmail[$pNumber]="$v1, $v3"

#appendvar+="; ${arrmail[$pNumber]}"

#if [ ! -z "${arrmail[$pNumber]}" ]

#        then
#           {arrmail[$pNumber]}="${arrmail[$ADresult1]}"
#else

#   {arrmail[$ADresult1]}="$appendvar"
#fi

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                        v1=` echo $v1 | tr '"' ' ' `
 #                       SUBJECT=" ${v1}, ${v3} - Your Development Machine Status Update"

  #                      TO="${pNumber}@edwardjones.com"

   #                     v4=` echo $v4 | tr '"' ' ' `

#           devmailmessage="\nGreetings ${NAME[0]}, \n\nI am in the process of cleaning up the machines in our lab.\n\nAssigned device: ${v1} \n\nEffort: ${v3}\n\nThe above machine have been assigned to you since ${v4}.\n\nDo you still need this machine or can I reclaim it?\nIf this machine is still required, please let us know how much longer you will need it.\nPlease keep in mind that Dev. workstations or laptops can only be assigned for 90 days due to licensing restrictions.\n\nIf this machine is no longer needed, please let us know also.\n\nThis machine will be rebuilt on or after $ExtDate.\n\nPlease reply to dev-tools@edwardjones.com by $ExtDate.\n\n\nThank you,\n\nDevelopment Environment Support team\ndev-tools@edwardjones.com "

 #                       echo -e ${devmailmessage}| mail -s "$SUBJECT" $TO -- -f $TO_TEAM
#       else
 #                           TO=`echo "ACTION REQUIRED: Email address cannot be determined for the following user: ${v2}, with assigned device: ${v1}. Please email this user yourself."`
               fi

#            else
 #                          TO=`echo "ACTION REQUIRED: Email address cannot be determined for the following user: ${v2}, with assigned device: ${v1}. Please email this user yourself."`

    fi
#echo -e "\n$TO ${v2}, ${v1}" >> confirmation.txt
echo "NEXT ROW"

done < csvfile.txt

#----------------------------------------------
#sending out confirmation email to dev-tools
#----------------------------------------------
#subject="WW - Notification Emails to Developers - Status"
#cat confirmation.txt |  mail -s "$subject" $TO_TEAM -- -f $TO_TEAM

#echo -e "Result: Processing is COMPLETED. Please check the ${Purple}$subject${ColorOFF} email. Note: ${Purple}$FILENAME${ColorOFF} file was deleted from ${Purple}$FILEDIR${ColorOFF} directory to avoid duplicates in the future."
rm ${CSVFILE}
rm csvfile.txt
rm confirmation.txt

else
#----------------------------------------------------
#if the directory is empty
#------------------------------------------------------
echo -e "Please make sure the CSV file was downloaded to ${Purple}$FILEDIR${ColorOFF} directory and run the script again."

fi


###
#--------THE END---------------------------------
###
```

Here's some of the output of the script.

- IFS=,
- read v1 v2 v3 v4 other
  ++ echo p098650
  ++ tr '"/,\&' ' '
- v2=p098650
- NAME=(${v2})
- cnt=1
- [[ p098650 =~ [P|p][[:digit:]]{6}$|[J|j][[:digit:]]{5}$ ]]
  ++ getent passwd p098650
  ++ awk -F: '{print $1}'
- ADresult1=p098650
- echo p098650
  p098650
- declare -A arrmail
- arrmail[$ADresult1]='CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00'
- appendvar+='; CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00'
- '[' '!' -z 'CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00' ']'
- echo CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00
  CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00
- echo 'NEXT ROW'
  NEXT ROW
- IFS=,
- read v1 v2 v3 v4 other
  ++ echo p098650
  ++ tr '"/,\&' ' '
- v2=p098650
- NAME=(${v2})
- cnt=1
- [[ p098650 =~ [P|p][[:digit:]]{6}$|[J|j][[:digit:]]{5}$ ]]
  ++ getent passwd p098650
  ++ awk -F: '{print $1}'
- ADresult1=p098650
- echo p098650
  p098650
- declare -A arrmail
- arrmail[$ADresult1]='CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00'
- appendvar+='; CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00'
- '[' '!' -z 'CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00' ']'
- echo CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00
  CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00
- echo 'NEXT ROW'
  NEXT ROW

What's I'm expecting to see is, arrmail[$ADresult1]='CNU327B1Y3, EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00';'CNU327B1GP, BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00'

I couldn't include a screenshot of the CSV, so I'm just going to cut and paste some of it.

Sernum $V1  Username $V2    Effort  $V3 Startdate $V4

CNU327B1Y3  p098650   EDGARLITE_0340_COR_00 4-Mar-14

CNU3199N31  Bell      SDLCONTENTPORTER_2013_COR_00  10-Mar-14

CNU327B1GP  p098650   BUZZLITE_0340_COR_00  4-Mar-14

CNU2479GLB  Mike      XENDESKAGENTX64_0640_COR_00   28-Feb-14

CNU327B1PB  Mike Bell   BONDONEUOBRA_2001_COR_00    6-Mar-14

2UA24705YY  Bell Mike   SASENTGUIDEX64_0610_COR_00  25-Nov-13

CNU2479K7Z  Bell, Mike  Software Testing    12-Dec-13

2UA24705ZZ  Bell Mike   TESTGUIDEX64_0610_COR_00    25-Nov-13

I know this is a lot.  I've been working on this for a long time and I'm trying to gain a greater understanding of how to use and manipulate arrays.  Also if you have an recommendations on books covering the subject, I'll be happy to review those also.  Thank you in advance for all the help.

Comment: The lines _literally_ look like `arrmail[p100]=Y2K, Y2J`? I thought you said they were CSVs; CSV files don't start with `arrmail[foo]=`. Please provide **literal** examples of the input; the best answer may be something that doesn't use bash arrays at all (for instance, the best answer might be an awk script or a join command).

Comment: (...and to be clear -- I personally use associative arrays in my scripts all the time and think they're a great feature, but if you're asking a question about how to get something done, that question should be asked in a way that's general enough to allow folks to provide answers that use tools other than the one you expect).

Comment: Anyhow -- more important to show the _literal_ input files (at least a few lines) and the _literal_ desired output (in terms of what can/should be generated from those previously-shown input lines). I don't want to discourage showing your work -- it's good to have some idea of what you've tried so far, so long as that doesn't overwhelm/hide the actual question -- but there's a Fred Brooks quote that rings true here: "Show me your flowcharts and conceal your tables, and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won’t usually need your flowcharts; they’ll be obvious."

Comment: Thanks Charles.  I appreciate you reaching out.  I'm going to post my script that I'm working on and some of the output for it.